# onKeyPress event with hardware Keyboard

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard

I'm trying to trigger `onKeyPress` event in my React-Native project (i need to get the KeyCode)

But i've see from React-Native docs `onKeyPress` not work on Android for harware Keyboard. So, with TextInput, how i can trigger this event from hardware Keyboard ? Maybe change approche and try to get the KeyCode from letter ?

Not : library like react-native-keyevent or react-native-external-keyboard not work in my case : i'm with TextInput usecase, not an global keyboard event.

Thank you !